# Active process when it should be in sleep

Tags: c, process, fork, sleep, suspend

Can anyone explain me why the child process is active, according to the output of waitpid() in the next lines of code? I've got stuck on this.

```
int main(){
   int p;
   if (!(p = fork())){sleep(10);
      return;}

   int s;
   sleep(1);
   printf("%d \n", waitpid(p,&s, WNOHANG|WUNTRACED));
   kill(p,2);
   return 0;
}
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: Why write contorted C?  What's wrong with `if ((p = fork()) == 0)` as a condition? (Not everyone would agree with me, but you get my comments from me and others can comment differently.) Your `return;` statement should be `return 0;` and your compiler should be complaining. What do you mean by 'the child process is active'? It sleeps for 10 seconds. Your parental code sleeps for 1 second, does a `waitpid()` which usually fails (because the child hasn't finished sleeping yet), and then you interrupt the child (why is the 2 not written `SIGINT`?). What are you seeing; what are you expecting?

Comment: You should error check your system calls, and print salient information (like PIDs, and the value in `s` after the `waitpid()` if the `waitpid()` reports success, and check the `kill()` too.  Note that `waitpid()` returning doesn't tell you much other than whether the child is dead (which it won't be).  There's a difference between sleeping (not dead, and program may wake again — unless it is killed first) and being dead (no chance of waking again).

Comment: waitpid() returns 0 and I was expecting from it to return the PID of child process. This is what I don't understand. If child process is suspended, why does waitpid() return 0 instead of the PID of child?

Comment: The [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) specification
says: _If `waitpid()` was invoked with `WNOHANG` set in options, it has at least one child process specified by `pid` for which status is not available, and status is not available for any process specified by `pid`, 0 is returned._  What you're seeing is precisely according to specification.  The child has not died yet, so you can't get a status, but because you used `WNOHANG`, you get 0 and an immediate return, rather than waiting until the child exits.

Comment: Yes, I've got it. Sorry, I realize it was a dumb question. The documentation I was using contains a mistake. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Bad luck on finding the documentation bug; it happens, though relatively rarely.  Please report it so it can be fixed.  I've converted my commentary into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*Comments turned into an answer with expanded information.*</sup>

#### Initial asides

- Your `return;` statement should be `return 0;` and your compiler should be complaining about a return with no value in a function that returns a value.
- Why write contorted C? What's wrong with `if ((p = fork()) == 0)` as a condition? (Not everyone would agree with me, but you get my comments from me and others can comment differently if they choose to do so.)
- You should error check your system calls, and print salient information (like PIDs, and the value in `s` after the `waitpid()` if the `waitpid()` reports success, and check the `kill()` too. Note that `waitpid()` returning doesn't tell you much other than whether the child is dead (which it won't be). There's a difference between sleeping (not dead, and program may wake again — unless it is killed first) and being dead (no chance of waking again).  The `waitpid()` function only reports on dead children (or untraced/stopped children — not an issue here), not on children that are still alive, even if they're just asleep, waiting on a signal.

### Your problem

What do you mean by 'the child process is active'? It sleeps for 10 seconds. Your parental code sleeps for 1 second, does a `waitpid()` which returns immediately, usually reporting that there are no dead children (because the child hasn't finished sleeping yet), and then you interrupt the child (why is the `2` not written `SIGINT`?).

What are you seeing; what are you expecting?

> `waitpid()` returns 0 and I was expecting from it to return the PID of child process. This is what I don't understand. If child process is suspended, why does waitpid() return 0 instead of the PID of child?

### POSIX [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html)

The specification says:

> #### Return value
>
> If `wait()` or `waitpid()` returns because the status of a child process is available, these functions shall return a value equal to the process ID of the child process for which status is reported. If `wait()` or `waitpid()` returns due to the delivery of a signal to the calling process, -1 shall be returned and `errno` set to [EINTR]. *If `waitpid()` was invoked with WNOHANG set in `options`, it has at least one child process specified by `pid` for which status is not available, and status is not available for any process specified by `pid`, 0 is returned.* Otherwise, -1 shall be returned, and `errno` set to indicate the error.

<sup>Emphasis added</sup>

What you're seeing is precisely according to specification. The child has not died yet, so you can't get a status, but because you used `WNOHANG`, you get 0 and an immediate return, rather than waiting until the child exits.